# Seeing blocky artifacts in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bootswatch

In the last few weeks, I've noticed my web application has developed some strange graphical glitches. I assumed that my video card was misbehaving and ignored it, since none of the relevant code had changed. Then I noticed the same thing on a coworker's machine, and then confirmed that everyone was seeing it. All machines are Win64, though a mashup of Windows 7 and Windows 10. The application itself uses bootswatch, which essentially themes bootswatch. A screenshot is below

[image: Chrome display bug]

I've since learned the following:

- It occurs in Chrome but not Firefox
- Using an older build of Chromium hosted [here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Win_x64/440007/), it does not occur. In newer versions it does.
- It is exaggerated by hovering over display elements
- It does not happen in (all) other bootswatch themes

I have created a minimal reproduction below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Chrome Artifact Repro</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/slate/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        .menu-item {
        padding: 0 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        }

        .menu-item.active {
            color: #5bc0de;
        }

        .menu-item:hover {
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span title="Span A" class="menu-item active">A</span>
                <span title="Span B" class="menu-item">B</span>
                <span title="Span C" class="menu-item">C</span>
                <span title="Span D" class="menu-item active">D</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </body>
</html>
```